# my wordpress theme Media Queries break point @media (max-width: 576px) is not being supported in chrome

Tags: wordpress

@media  (max-width: 576px) {} this is my media query for all the mobile device it is working well on safari but it's not on google chrome

on safari it is rendering @media (max-width: 576px){ .work{color:red} }

but on chrome, the query is not showing at all

Comment: try `@media all and (max-width: 576px) {} `

Comment: and clear your caches

Comment: i have tried but it is still not working

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When asking a question, try to format your code properly so that we can better visualize your code. Also, provide your desired output and further clarification.

Comment: Just a guess: 
Maybe you are Zoomed in or Zoomed out in chrome browser? Try to CTRL+Scroll up or down and set zoom to 100%